# Django ManyToManyField add user

Tags: django

At the moment i'm learning about ManyToManyField.I have a scenario which I don't understand completely.

For example this is my module.I created 3 accounts called Jim , Tony and Mary

I get the user Mary to follow Jim. I can easily make Mary follow Jim by clicking on Jim at the dropbox at the admin page
I'm been trying to figure out how would I get Mary to follow jim using the manytomanyfield at the shell prompt with only these information . The User objects of Mary
and the username of Jim.

```
Mary = User.objects.get(username='Mary')
Jim = User.objects.get(username='Jim')
```

How can I get Mary to follow jim? just like in the admin page

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: This is the field that I don't understand. Hands-off :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mary = User.objects.get(username='Mary')
jim = User.objects.get(username='Jim')

#just make sure your user is saved before adding the relationship.

jim.following.add(mary)
jim.save()
```

When specifying what you did with your extra fields is basically describing how you want the relationship to work.

What this `models.ManyToManyField()` is doing behind the scenes is to create a intermediary database table, normally looking something like this "app_model1_model2", naming might be off but you get the idea.

`self` means that you're defining a relationship with, that's right, the same model.
Thusly, you won't get a `user_set` but since you've decided that its `False` in `symmetry` you'll get one since you're forcing Django to add one.

Meaning in code will be that you can do `user.user_set.all()` to get all its related users!

`related_name='followers'` means that you're naming you relationship `followers` instead of the Django generated name, I think it'll be something along the lines of "users" otherwise.
Ie. you're giving it a better meaning and representation of what you're trying to achieve.

This is explained really well in the docs!

[Django docs ManyToMany-fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: I got confused , it said you need to specify all the detail for the relationship required by the model . The simple add, create and assignment calls don’t provide a way to specify this extra detail. So I though I need to specify all the details of the Person module before I could save https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/

Comment: If I understand you correctly then, you need to specify it on Model level but not on "add"-level.

Comment: @donkeyboy72 No worries and added some explanation as well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> Mary = User.objects.get(username='Mary')
>>> Jim = User.objects.get(username='Jim')
>>> Jim.following.add(Mary)
>>> Jim.save()
```

[Django ManyToMany example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) from the django book